# How to Determine What's Using Filling GPU's Video Memory?

Tags: macos, video, memory

I have a system with integrated graphics to which OS X has assigned 1.5gb (out of 16gb) of RAM, however iStat Menus is currently reporting this at around 95% full, even though I'm not currently running anything that should be making much of a demand of the GPU.

Of course it's possible there's something I'm not aware of that has been using the GPU, but only restarting has completely cleared it. I was playing Civilisation V yesterday, but even while playing it didn't fill my video memory, and that was over 10 hours ago (my computer hasn't been asleep since then, as I'm still running through a large initial backup of a huge volume).

I'm just wondering if there's an easy way to determine what's using up all this video memory, similar to using Activity Monitor to track main memory? If it happens again I'd like to figure out what's at fault so I can avoid the problem in future and/or report any memory leaks or similar issues.

Comment: Full memory isn't 'wasted' memory. Yosemite handles memory differently to previous OSes. It doesn't flush RAM just so it can sit there idle, it keeps it full of the potentially most wanted data.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder but it's not the main memory I'm interested in, but the chunk of RAM that's assigned to the integrated GPU. OS X has set 1.5gb for my HD4600 GPU, and if that's full then that's 1.5gb lost from main memory, and wasted if the GPU isn't actually doing anything important.

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool available to check a lot of graphic card parameters: OpenGL Drive Monitors

You may download it at [Apple developer](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action). You need a developer account though. Search for "Graphics Tools" and then download "Graphics Tools for Xcode - Xcode 6.1". Open the .dmg and copy "OpenGL Drive Monitors" to your Application folder.

You can't track down graphic memory usage of individual apps though.

Screenshot:

[image: opengl]

Comment: Should help at least, but does that mean that tracking app video memory usage is impossible, or are just no tools for it specifically?

Comment: @Haravikk Let's say: It's not as easy to track as app RAM with Activity Monitor because vRAM is much more volatile. Another tool provided by Apple in the same .dmg is "OpenGL Profiler" but i have to fiddle with it before i may tell more.